# Get field data type from MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have some fields in mongodb such as name as string, id as integer, address as arraylist and so on.  I need name as **"what data type"**. I need to get the name datatype.

This is my coding config the netbeans and MongoDB

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongopath);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbname);
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(dbname);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below:

```
BasicDBObject doc = cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : new BasicDBObject();
Object name = doc.get("name");
String typeString = name == null ? "null" : name.getClass().toString();
```

Comment: Thank u Wizard.. It working fine.. i got below output class java.lang.String.. I need String data  type only. Can u explain this?

Comment: @Bass: String typeString = name == null ? "null" : name.getClass().getSimpleName();

Comment: Thank u Wizard and i have Other one doubt please check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665118/get-document-word-file-content-from-azure-storage-using-java

Comment: @Bass, I'm not familiar with that. :)