# Get Document/word file content from Azure Storage using java.

Tags: java, azure

I upload image and document file in Blob-Azure storage. I know,how to get the blob property(name,url ,etc) using java.

But My Problem :**I Need get document file content**.

my document content : The Azure Table storage service stores large amounts of structured data.

How to access the document content..

Thank u

Comment: Is this link helpful ? - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/#DownloadBlob

Comment: Thank u Naveen. I already used this Url.. My suggestion not there at the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for my problem. Here is the code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(blob.openInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

It may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest perhaps starting with: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/

From there you'll find a deeper link on "How to: Download a Blob". This should hopefully get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thank u for your support. i would read the document file content without download.. Any suggest ?

Comment: Sorry but there's no way to "get the content" without downloading that content to either local memory or disk so that a program can operate on it. So I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish.